# Why is .val('') stripping out the single quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following bit of jQuery code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#results").on('click', 'input:checkbox', function() {
    // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
      // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
      // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
      var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
      // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
      // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
      $(group).prop("checked", false);
      $box.prop("checked", true);
      $('#wp_theme_url').val($(this).val());
      $('#wp_theme_slug').val($(this).data("themeslug"));
    } else {
      $box.prop("checked", false);
      $('#wp_theme_url').val('');
      $('#wp_theme_slug').val('');
    } 
  });
});
```

However, if I unselect a checkbox it strips out the ='' from the value attribute resulting in

```
<input ... value>
```

instead of

```
<input ... value=''>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: And what is the problem about that? `value` is equal to `value=''`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong. It's still a valid HTML. What matter is the value in the internal memory

Comment: [8.1.2.3. Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#elements-attributes) `[...]Empty attribute syntax: Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.[...]`

Comment: @t.niese oh, ok, I didn't know that.

Comment: Ok, so the issue was my PHP code and not the jQuery. I thought that it was not returning an empty value because of the stripped out ="". I'm a newbie to forgive the ignorance. Issue is solved. Thanks to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute only contains the default value and not the actual live value.